# How to avoid the focused cell color in grid control

Tags: wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I have a grid control,I don't need to show any default color(cell and row) when i clicked on the grid,I tried with some code to disable the default selected row color of grid but when i applied this code its worked as my expected bu the problem is that the border of grid is gone also

```xml
<dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView ShowGroupPanel="False" Name="View1" >
                    <dxg:TableView.RowStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="dxg:GridViewBase.IsFocusedRow" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="dxg:RowControl.Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </dxg:TableView.RowStyle>
                    <dxg:TableView.CellStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="dxg:GridViewBase.IsFocusedCell" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="dxg:RowControl.Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </dxg:TableView.CellStyle>
                </dxg:TableView>
            </dxg:GridControl.View>
```

[image: This is the grid view]

Here we can see that the second row border is missing in the grid

Please help me to sort out this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Try to look over [this article](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/6764/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Examples/Styles-and-Templates/How-to-Change-the-Appearance-of-the-Focused-Data-Row-and-Focused-Cell)

Look carefully how to use **FocusedRowStyle**

Other words - I think using the **FocusedRowStyle** instead of **RowStyle** may solve this problem.